# What is the correct procedure to create images/sprite for iPhone/iPad apps/games?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I am new in developing games with Xcode for iPhone/iPad. Thus I need some help with the correct procedure to create images/sprites for the game.

By now I have created my sprites with Illustrator and I exported them as PDF files. In Xcode I created this single scale asset and put the PDF in it.

If I understand the documentation correctly, Xcode automatically generates image files at `@1x`, `@2x` and `@3x` from the PDF. Does it generate PNG files?

Then I create a `SKSpriteNode` and set the size like this: `abc.size = CGSize(width: 123, height: 123)`. Instead of `123`, I fill in the width and height corresponding to the frame/image size I set up in Illustrator. Is this correct? I think so, because this is `@1x` version?!

But if I need the same image for iPhone and iPad in different sizes, i can't simply resize it, because the `@1x` image version isn't a vector anymore and bounded to the frame size I chose in Illustrator? What to do then? Do I have to resize my image in Illustrator and export it in a different size?

What is the correct procedure? Do I have to draw a sketch with pencil at the very beginning on a paper and the measure it with ruler? Then I would go to illustrator and set the frame width height at that what I measured manually?

So many questions. I am very confused with this images sizes, resolutions and `@1x`, `@2x` and `@3x` version. I am not sure why I should use vector files, if I still can't resize the images in the developing process as I would like to, because they are still bound to the frame size I chose in Illustrator.

Is there no possibility to set ratios between all my images and then just use the vector PDF file? **How should I setup my Illustrator?**

*I hope somebody can bring some light into the dark. Thank you.*

Comment: +1000000 x a million. The Apple docs on this are bewildering, and it doesn't seem like any artists or programmers have ever put up with each other long enough to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your pdf should be sized in points @1x (not pixels).  The points should be the same physical size on the phone and the ipad, but if you want them smaller on the phone you need a second set of images; the asset catalog lets you swap out images based on iphone/ipad.  Xcode renders your pdf to png's @1x, @2x and @3x and your app will pick the correct png based on the resolution of the device.  You are correct that these are no longer vector assets and that scaling them up could leave you with blurry/pixelated images.  You have a couple of choices:

1) include a scaled up version of your image at its maximum scale in app and use this version only when you need to scale up (otherwise its a waste of memory and processing if you are always rendering a much smaller image).  This is probably the easiest solution.

2) leave your assets as vectors and load them as vectors,  You still can render them to images for performance at a constant scale or range of scales, but you can always re-render them at any scale if needed.  Most likely you want to use an [SVG library](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) for this.

3) You can directly import your assets as code using a program such as [paint code](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/).  There used to be similar plugins for illustrator but I haven't seen one for Swift 3/Illustrator CC.  This is obviously faster than #2 since there is no need to decode the vector file.  If your file has a lot of overdraw you may still want to rasterize to images for performance.

Comment: with all due respect, I think you might have answered what you think is a generic question with a generic answer. The question isn't as generic as it first might seem.

Comment: Of course the irony is that there should be a generic set of steps that answer these questions of production workflow, but it doesn't appear that there is, and these certainly aren't them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've found from my experience:

1) Xcode does not generate @2x and @3x from .png files. It can't really - you need to manually supply @1x, @2x, and @3x sizes.

2) Whatever size you use for the CGSize(...), that should be your @1x image, then generate @2x, and @3x from that. I started by designing the size of a level in the scene editor, then made a generic SKSpriteNode shape just to get the size I wanted, then I started making the image from the size I found that looks good.

3) Xcode supports vector based graphics (svg, pdf), but you can't use them as part of a texture atlas, which makes them much less useful in my opinion.